# Execute & save log

Tags: bash

I am executing script on the Arguments via loop and saving logs in one file.
How to use Args command to run at a time all in once.
Below tried 
args -n -500

But this doesn't save logs , How to appends to save logs here ?

Comment: Does the order of write to file_save matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to [group](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) the inner loop commands and redirect their output to a file indexed by the same index `$i`, then push all together in the background `&`. Something like

```bsh
for i in $(cat $file_name)
do
    (echo "$i"; /path/script.pl "$i") >> "${file_save}-${i}" &
done
```

Also instead `for` and `cat` in this case I would use `while` and `read` in some way like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file_name='in_file'

while IFS= read -r i
do
        (echo "$i"; /path/script.pl "$i") >> "${file_save}-${i}" 2>&1 &
done < "$file_name"
```

Here `2>&1` is added in case you want to have and the error messages in your log file. More about the construction `IFS= read -r line` could be found in this [encyclopedic answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209184/201297) provided by @StéphaneChazelas.

In addition, if the execution of `./script.pl` takes really long time you can detach from the current shell in case you accidentally close the terminal window where the main script was started. For this purpose you can use [`nohup mycommand &`](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm) instead just `&`.

---

According to the above scenario probably the easiest way to merge all logs in one file is to use a loop again (once all jobs from the main script finish) in such way:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file_name='in_file'
merged_log='out_file'

>"$merged_log"   # empty the merged log file - not mandatory if the file doesn't exist

while IFS= read -r i
do
        cat "${file_save}-${i}" >> "$merged_log"
        rm "${file_save}-${i}"
done < "$file_name"
```

This also should work:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

file_name='in_file'
merged_log='out_file'

while IFS= read -r i
do
        cat "${file_save}-${i}"
        rm "${file_save}-${i}"
done < "$file_name" > "$merged_log"
```

Comment: Hi @Tom15, in order to merge couple of files you need to use the command `cat` (concatenate). Actually it is designed for this purpose, the syntax is: `cat file-1 file-2 file-etc > merged-file`. I will elaborate my answer later today and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

If order of write does not matter,

```
for i in $(cat $file_name);do echo $i; ./script.pl $i>>file & done
```

This is parallel.

Comment: Thus `echo $i` will go in to the STDOUT not in the log file.

Comment: Isn't requirement to write $i to stdout and output of script to the file?